# Is there a way to join nodes of a network based upon an underlying image?

Tags: python, image-processing, scipy, scikit-image

### The Goal

My aim here is to:

1. Take a skeletonised image consisting of multiple intersecting non-straight lines
2. Detect corners using a harris corner detect
3. Join these corner nodes into a graph based upon whether two corners are connected by the underlying image

The first two parts are relatively trivial using the `skeletonize()` and `corner_harris()` functions from `scikit-image`, however the third part has me stumped.

The following code (given an image of white lines on a black background) allows us to get to a stage where we have a KDtree of nodes that signify corners detected in the image:

```
import skimage.io as io
from skimage.morphology import skeletonize
from skimage.color import rgb2gray
from skimage.feature import corner_harris, corner_peaks
from scipy.spatial import KDTree

# Load image (~1500*900px) and convert to grey
testimage = io.imread("imagepath.png")[:,:,:3]
testimage = (rgb2gray(testimage) > 0)

# Skeletonise and detect corners
skel = skeletonize(testimage)
coords = corner_peaks(corner_harris(skel), min_distance=5, threshold_rel=0.01)

# Generate tree and find pairs that are within a certain distance
# (This stops us having to try EVERY possible connection)
tree = KDTree(coords)
pairs = list(tree.query_pairs(25))    # Arbitrary distance
```

Below is the outcome of plotting the detected corners over my test source image.
[image: A sample image with nodes plotted over the source image]

---

### The Question

My trouble comes with deciding which of the candidate connections (stored above as `pairs`) are to be kept based upon the ground truth image.

If the lines were straight I would just plot lines between the nodes and check whether the pixels under the line match a threshold, however most lines are not entirely straight.

If the corner detection was perfect I could use those nodes as a starting point and then try to traverse along a line until I hit another node, but as the corner is not perfectly on a line, this may not be feasible.

I have tried playing with using the `active_contour()` function but parameterising this is exceptionally hard to do in a way that works across the image, and even then it has a tendency to not entirely fit, and thus lead to a lot of false negatives.

---

### Current Thoughts

My current thought is to do something like the following:

1. Do a pass over all corners, snapping them to the nearest white pixel.
2. Check a 5x5 kernel around each corner to work out which directions lines emerge from the corner
3. Try to make a turtle iteratively traverse lines in these directions until they hit another node

But overall this feels like a problem that might have been solved in CV or ML applications. I just *cannot for the life of me* find anything that looks promising!

Is there an easy way to do this that I've just completely missed?

Comment: You should not use Harris on a binary image. This is a common mistake, very much like using Canny on a binary image. The skeleton pixels that have more than two neighbors are branch points. This is all you need to do to identify the nodes in your graph. Then, indeed, starting at each branch pixel, follow the neighbors until you reach another branch pixel. This has already been implemented many times, I’m sure you can find working code if you use the right key words (which I think I’ve given you here).

Comment: @CrisLuengo Ah, that bit of insight is an exceptionally useful one! Pixel traversal is pretty trivial but I was certainly overcomplicating the corner detection. Thank you and I will play with that today!

Answer (score 1):

The [`skan`](https://skeleton-analysis.org) package might do what you need, as alluded to by Cris's comment. (Disclaimer: I am the main author of skan.)

Comment: Thank you for this, a year later I can say it sent me down a rabbithole which ended up in me writing a similar package to skan (but with some differences particular to my use-cases). I'll eventually look to make it output the same csr representation to  allow for interoperability. For everyone else who is doing this sort of analysis though, skan really is a good place to look!

Comment: Ha! Very cool! If it makes sense, I'd be interested to collaborate and perhaps merge the packages! (+write a new paper.) Skan was indeed written for a specific use case but I love collaborating to generalise work to new domains. Feel free to open an issue in the skan repo if this sounds plausible and we can take it from there. If not, all good, godspeed! 